# Centering a bootstrap 3 progress bar horizontally?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, row

I am not able to center two progress bars inside two columns the same way used in the other 2 rows.

Currently:[image]

Expectation:[image: image2]

Progress bars code:

```
<div class="row top-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="progress" style="width:120px;">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">70%
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="progress" style="width:120px;">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">70%
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The two squares which seem to work:

```
<div class="row top-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="charBox">img1</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="charBox">img2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Top row is .top-row {margin-top: 20px;} just to distance the rows.

What would be the correct way to center those progress bars the same way as the other two rows? Appreciate some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Bootstrap doesn't have an option for this.. In itself but you can do it by adding your own class to the element and then adding some styling for that class.

Where you have your `col-md-6` add another class of `column-centered`

Then in your css do add in some styles...

```
.column-centered {
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```